# how to animate images in appcelerator (3D animate)

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying figure out how to create this effect [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKwmJ.png)

This is how amazon shows a book and make it animate a little to show it as a book.

I can setup an image ; make it spin etc - but I am not clear on how to make that image give a 3D effect on touch.

example:

[image]

on click if it became like so..

[image]

I understand from a prevous post that I can create 2 images and on click replace one with second.

IS there a way to use use the animate function to do the same ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this http://www.learningtitanium.com/mobile-api/ios/titanium-tilt-effect-using-3dmatrix.html.

It will definitely help you, just try to use different axis(y-axis probably will solve your problem) to get the correct rotation angle.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this module: https://github.com/AppWerft/TiFlipViewControler

It's not exactly the same but perhaps you can change it to get your look